# Am I using all the power of my PC in Ubuntu? How can I find this out?

Tags: cpu, power-management

My computer has a CPU with 4 *cores* and 4GB RAM.

What I want is to find out, if I am using all the available power that my PC offers to me? How can I do this?

Comment: It is difficult to tell what you are asking, please try to be more clear.

Comment: Are you asking if your PSU works at it's full potential all the time?

Comment: @ Marius Balaban Well, actually yes, that is what i am asking!I want to know if my cpu works with 4 cores and in it's  maximum speed. BUT not only my cpu but also the other pc parts! I want to have the control of my pc!thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I do believe - actually - you're using not just your PC at its full potential, you're also **wasting it**!

1. You've 4Gb of RAM, so 32 or 64 bits is the same. That's ok, you're correctly using all the available RAM.
2. You have 4 cores. Ubuntu is surely using them correctly, because it IS made to use everything at the maximum.

The problem is (or at least may be), you don't want to use all the powerhorses all the time! Electricity costs.

If you do care about this point, install cpufrequtils and this http://www.webupd8.org/2011/07/cpu-frequency-scaling-indicator-fixed.html.

Otherwise, you're good to go!